# Url loaded between every resource. JSF, OracleWebServer

Tags: jsf, weblogic, icefaces

At random (1 out of 100 maybe) the login page to a web application seems to not load any resources, including the CSS. When I was finally able to recreate this issue with network traffic monitored I found some very strange behavior. First, the html page contents get loaded after each resource fetch (see pic 1). Second, all the resource fetches have completely empty response bodies (not shown). Third when I click submit, the normal POST action by j_security_check gets run, but it doesn't seem to do anything and one of the javascript files that is supposed to be fetched and run at the beginning of the page load attemps to be saved to the computer instead. The javascript file is fetched near the bottom, called autocomplete.js.jsf. The contents of autocomplete.js.jsf is a simple framebuster security check:

```
/**
* Prevent FrameBuster attack
*/
if (window.top.location !== window.location) {
   window.top.location.href = document.location.href;
}
```

Below is an attached picture of the login page and the network traffic. Sorry for all the black, but I am basically a contractor and want to avoid any clues of the client if I can.[image: The buggy load with network traffic]

Below is what the login page is supposed to look like, with normal web traffic.
[image]

Project Info:

I am working on Icefaces v3.3 running on a weblogic v12 server.

I have no idea why this is happening. If anybody could shed some light on why the network traffic looks the way it does, and why it affects the page the way it does I would be very grateful.